# Q: F#: Iterate through highscore file and pick top 3

Tags: f#, console-application

On my mission to master F# I'm creating a pocket game.
I'm at the point where I want to implement some sort of a highscore list.

So far I'm writing **Name**, **Score** and **Time** to a file which then reads in to the application displaying all previous scores. *Yes, this isn't ideal as the list grows pretty quick.*

I somewhat want to pick the top 3 scores, not caring about **Name** or **Time**.

**Question:** Should I read the file into an array/list and from there pick out the top scores or is there a nicer way to pick out the top scores directly from the file?

Pointers, Code, Tips and Tricks are warmly welcome.

```
let scoreFile = sprintf ("Name: %s\nTime: %i sec\nScore: %d\n\n") name stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds finalScore
let readExistingFile = File.ReadAllText ("hiscore.txt")
File.WriteAllText ("hiscore.txt", scoreFile + readExistingFile)
let msg = File.ReadAllText ("hiscore.txt")
printfn "\nHighscores:\n\n%s\n\n\n\nPress ANY key to quit." msg
```

Comment: You could just store only the top 3 (or maybe a few extras if you want) in the file instead of storing all high scores. Just read in the entire file and write out a replacement file with the current top 3 scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I read the file into an array/list and from there pick out the top scores or is there a nicer way to pick out the top scores directly from the file?

Unless the scores are already sorted in the file, you'll have to look through them all to find out what the Top 3 is. The way your file is written right now, parsing the data back might be a bit hard - scores are stored on multiple lines, so you'd have to handle that.

Assuming the file doesn't have to be human-friendly, I'd go with a list of comma-separated values instead. It's harder for a human to read by opening the file, but it makes it a *lot* easier to parse in your program. For example, if the lines looks like `Name,Time,Score`, they can be parsed like this:

```
type ScoreData = {
    Name  : string
    Time  : string // could be a DateTime, using string for simplicity
    Score : int
}

let readHighScores file =
    File.ReadAllLines file
    |> Array.choose (fun line ->
        match line.Split ',' with
        | [| name; time; score |] ->
            {
                Name  = name
                Time  = time
                Score = (int)score // This will crash if the score isn't an integer - see paragraph below.
            }
            |> Some
        | _ ->
            // Line doesn't match the expected format, we'll just drop it
            None
    )
    |> Array.sortBy (fun scoreData -> -scoreData.Score) // Negative score, so that the highest score comes first
    |> Seq.take 3
```

This will read through your file and output the three largest scores. Using Array.choose allows you to only keep lines that match the format you're expecting. This also lets you add extra validation as needed, such as making sure that the score is an integer and perhaps parsing the Time into a `System.DateTime` instead of storing it as an `int`.

You can then print your high scores by doing something like this:

```
let highScores = readHighScores "hiscore.txt"
printfn "High scores:"
highScores
|> Seq.iteri (fun index data ->
    printfn "#%i:" (index + 1)
    printfn "  Name:  %s" data.Name
    printfn "  Time:  %s" data.Time
    printfn "  Score: %i" data.Score
)
```

This calls the previously defined function and prints each of the scores returned - the top 3, in this case. Using `Seq.iteri`, you can include the index in the output in addition to the score data itself. Using some data I made up, it ends up looking like this:

```
High scores:
#1:
  Name:  Awots
  Time:  2015-06-15
  Score: 2300
#2:
  Name:  Roujo
  Time:  2016-03-01
  Score: 2200
#3:
  Name:  Awots
  Time:  2016-03-02
  Score: 2100
```

Now, there might be a way to do this without loading the entire file at once in memory, but I don't think it'd be worth it unless you have a really large file - in which case you might want to either keep it sorted or use a more fit storage method like a database.

Comment: Wow, I couldn't have asked for a better answer. Kudos to you Roujo, really! This was a huge eye-opener for me. Thanks a bunch for your time and effort! Just wanted to point out that the Time is the actual time elapsed in the game as my plan is to implement different time limits, i.e 10 seconds, 30 seconds or 60 seconds.

Comment: @Awots Ahhh, got it. Looks like it was right there in the code you submitted - I missed it the first time around, sorry. ^_^'